# getValue(String.class) vs getValue().toString();

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database

In FireBaseDp while retrieving data one can use one of the above methods to get value. I am wondering just what is the difference (any advantages /disadvantages with one or the other)?

Answer (score 1):

The exact behavior depends on the type of data that you're extracting.

If you're extracting a String value, the behavior of the two snippets is the same.