# getValue(String.class) vs getValue().toString()

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database

this is an example for a question asked here :

[getValue(String.class) vs getValue().toString();](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40142368/4227019)

I had stored into my firebase table a child "Vyear" as Integer and it looked as such

[image]

and I used to retrieve it as below, and the app was always crashing ;

```
child4.child("Vyear").getValue(String.class);
```

after reading the question, and the answers , I solved my problem and now I am using;

```
child4.child("Vyear").getValue().toString();
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is posted as an explanation to another question present and is not a valid question itself.

Comment: @PradyumanDixit I somehow did read a question into it, so wrote up how the two snippets are different. But you may be right too, so Naderco-jo: if you meant to answer the linked question, you should enter the same information as an answer to that question.

Comment: You should edit the question and update the snippets there, posting a different question for explanation creates confusion.

Comment: I tried to answer the Original question, I was not allowed for some reason.

Answer (score 2):

Your first snippet:

```
child4.child("Vyear").getValue(String.class);
```

This retrieves the `String` value from `Vyear`. Since `Vyear` stores a numeric value, it means that the snippet returns `null`.

The second snippet:

```
child4.child("Vyear").getValue().toString();
```

This returns the value from `Vyear` in its underlying type. So if `Vyear` has a value, this returns a number (a `long` or `Long`). Calling `toString()` on that, gives you the number as a string.

Note that in case `Vyear` does not exist, the second snippet will thow a `NullPointerException` on the call to `toString()`.